# Can you use a swift action during a full round action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions

Are you allowed to use a [swift action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Swift-Actions) in the middle of a [full round action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Round-Actions) like full attack?

> The only movement you can take during a full attack is a 5-foot step. You may take the step before, after, or **between** your attacks.

That seems to support that you can take those small actions between aspects of the full round action.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the page you linked,

> You can take a swift action anytime you would normally be allowed to take a free action.

According to the description of free actions:

> You can perform one or more free actions while taking another action normally. However, there are reasonable limits on what you can really do for free, as decided by the GM.

So, yes, you can perform a swift action while performing a full-round action, but your GM might decide that certain combinations of swift actions and other actions might be too silly to be allowed.