# Quickened Chill Touch and full attack

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, metamagic, touch-attacks

Given that, as far as I can understand, the most common interpretation of the spell is that it gives you X charges, and then you are "holding the charge" until you use all the charges to make successful melee touch attacks (plus the first attack after casting the spell) or you cast another spell.

Now, I'm having a few doubts about this spell when you cast it quickened:

1. Can you make a full attack in the same round?
2. Do they have to be normal unarmed attacks to make a full attack, or can they all be melee touch attacks?
3. Do you also make the touch attack given by the spell as soon as you cast it (from what I read, you make the touch attack as part of the spell even when you quicken it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes, and yes.

1. We already have [a Q&A on swift actions and full-round actions in Pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84285/4563), and the rules are the same in D&D 3.5e: you can use a swift action [any time you could use a free action](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#swiftActions) (barring, of course, when you have already used a swift action that round), and full-round actions like a full-attack specify that [you can use free actions alongside them](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullRoundAction). The fact that the swift action in this case was a casting of *quickened chill touch* is irrelevant.
2. When you get to make an attack or attacks, you are free to use any weapon you have available to do so (barring special cases like Two-Weapon Fighting where limitations on which weapons may be used are introduced). Characters holding a charge of *chill touch* [are considered armed with that charge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#armedUnarmedAttacks), so that is a weapon you can use for any given attack you get: attacks in a full-attack, attacks of opportunity, whatever.
3. Yes, *chill touch* says that part of its effect includes making a touch attack, so you do so as part of the swift action you use to cast *quickened chill touch*. Nothing in [Quicken Spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#quickenSpell) specifies that you lose that attack:

   > Casting a quickened spell is an swift action. You can perform another action, even casting another spell, in the same round as you cast a quickened spell. You may cast only one quickened spell per round. A spell whose casting time is more than 1 full round action cannot be quickened. A quickened spell uses up a spell slot four levels higher than the spell’s actual level. Casting a quickened spell doesn’t provoke an attack of opportunity.

   <sup>(the entire text of Quicken Spell’s benefit, which makes no mention of losing touch attacks)</sup>

   For most touch-attack spells, that would make the quickened version actually worse, since you would spend a swift action to cast and then a standard to attack, instead of just a standard to cast and attack. (Yes, I realize in some situations splitting them up would be beneficial, but those are unusual.)